# Redux not updating state correctly -- state stays as empty array despite adding an object in the line prior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update my React Redux state using the usual practice. You immutably copy your current state into the return function and then overwrite the properties which are to have a new value.

My expected result is to have

`state.copy`

update to

```
[
    { webCopy: "", id: 0 },
    { webCopy: "", id: 1 }
]
```

Unfortunately, it's an empty array despite returning the copy value as a new array with a JS object inside.

I've tried looking at StackOverflow search results for `"react redux state not updating correctly"` but none of the search results seem to match my situation.

In my app I've even checked: Only

`case actionTypes.ADD_COMPONENT`

(the first one in the reducer) activates at this part of the app. It is literally a button click which triggers

`ADD_COMPONENT`

on its own. There is no activity from any other reducer that could be overwriting my state with an empty `[]` array.

Why am I ending up with an empty array at the end of `case actionTypes.ADD_COMPONENT`?

My `console.log()` statement even shows a JavaScript Object being the value for `newCopy` RIGHT BEFORE I RETURN a new state.

So here is reducer.js. I've uploaded the COMPLETE reducer instead of just `case actionTypes.ADD_COMPONENT` where the error is taking place:

```js
import * as actionTypes from "./constants";

let component = "";
let idIteration = null;
let stateArray = [];
let tempCopy = [];

const initialState = {
  components: [],
  uniqueIdCounter: 0,
  currentPage: 1,
  copy: [],
  siteURL: "/salespage/"
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // you can probably ignore everything outside of this switch statement
    // this is the important switch statement
    case actionTypes.ADD_COMPONENT:
      stateArray = [...state.components];
      console.log("state:", state);
      console.log("State Copy:", state.copy);
      component = action.payload[0]; // will be "Header", "Headline", "Text Area", "Image", "Email Field", "Footer"
      if (component === "Header") {
        // append "Header" component to the beginning of the list
        stateArray.unshift({
          type: component,
          id: state.uniqueIdCounter
        });
      } else {
        // push component to the end of the list
        stateArray.push({
          type: component,
          id: state.uniqueIdCounter
        });
      }
      idIteration = state.uniqueIdCounter + 1;

      // SEND HELP. How could state.copy possibly be anything other than a JS object after these lines?
      let newCopy = [...state.copy];
      newCopy.push({ webCopy: "", id: action.payload[1] });
      console.log("TTTTTTTTT", newCopy);

      return {
        ...state,
        components: stateArray,
        uniqueIdCounter: idIteration,
        copy: newCopy // why doesn't this update the array to contain newCopy? it should.
      };

    // i don't know how any of this could possibly cause my state.copy to be equal to []
    case actionTypes.SET_NEW:
      console.log("Activating SET_NEW");
      // uploads the newly reordered set of components to state
      let uploadNewOrder = [...action.payload];
      return {
        ...state,
        components: uploadNewOrder
      };
    case actionTypes.DEL:
      console.log("activating DEL");
      // uploads the state less the deleted item
      let uploadShortened = [...action.payload];
      return {
        ...state,
        components: uploadShortened
      };
    case actionTypes.PAGE_CHANGE:
      console.log("activating PAGE_CHANGE");

      stateArray = [...state.components];
      return {
        ...state,
        // action.payload is set in each page's ComponentDidMount()
        currentPage: action.payload
      };
    case actionTypes.NEW_VAR:
      console.log("activating NEW_VAR");
      // case "NEW_VAR" fires from Customize's renderStateComponents()
      stateArray = [...state.components];
      tempCopy = Object.assign([], state.copy); // avoids the TypeError bug with [...state.copy]
      // push an empty copy datapoint to state with a unique id to use in identifying which copy goes where in interface
      let newInputFieldNumber = { webCopy: "", id: action.payload };
      tempCopy.push(newInputFieldNumber);
      return {
        ...state,
        components: stateArray,
        copy: tempCopy
      };
    case actionTypes.ADD_COPY:
      console.log("activating ADD_COPY");

      tempCopy = [...state.copy]; // immutably copy state.copy
      let textToAdd = action.payload[0];
      let indexToFind = action.payload[1];

      for (let i = 0; i < tempCopy.length; i++) {
        if (tempCopy[i].id === indexToFind) {
          // Modify the JS object linked to the appropriate input field
          tempCopy[i] = { webCopy: textToAdd, id: indexToFind };
        }
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        components: stateArray,
        copy: tempCopy
      };
    case actionTypes.SET_URL:
      console.log("activating SET_URL");

      stateArray = [...state.components];
      // TODO: handle cases like user entered www.etc.com and https://www.test.com
      let domain = action.payload;
      const notAllowed = [
        "https://www.",
        "www.",
        ".",
        "www",
        "com",
        "net",
        "org",
        ".com",
        ".net",
        ".org"
      ];
      for (let i = 0; i < notAllowed.length; i++) {
        if (domain.includes(notAllowed[i])) {
          domain = domain.replace(notAllowed[i], "");
        }
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        components: stateArray,
        siteURL: "/salespage/" + domain
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Any suggestions what to try? I tried adding this case to my reducer and activating it in the line after `.ADD_COMPONENT` and it's still yielding an empty array:

```
case actionTypes.PREP_COPY:

            let prepCopy = [...state.copy];
            prepCopy.push({ webCopy: "", id: action.payload });
            return {
                ...state,
                copy: prepCopy
            };
```

I gave the offending variable, `newCopy`, a unique name as to not use global scope. In case that matters somehow.

What other code could I show? Only a reducer can affect Redux state and there is no other code running besides .ADD_COMPONENT and (now) .PREP_COPY

EDIT:
As per suggestions, I've tried using the spread operator with my variables while returning state. The code now works if I use the Spread operator in BOTH Reducer Actions only. Using it in just one of them still yields an empty array. Like so:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_COMPONENT:
            // edited out some code...
            let newCopy = [...state.copy];
            newCopy.push({ webCopy: "", id: action.payload[1] });
            console.log("newCopy", newCopy);

            return {
                ...state,
                components: stateArray,
                uniqueIdCounter: idIteration,
                copy: [...newCopy]
            };

        case actionTypes.PREP_COPY:
            console.log("State.copy:", state.copy);
            let prepCopy = [...state.copy];
            prepCopy.push({ webCopy: "", id: action.payload });
            console.log("PREPCOPY:", prepCopy);
            return {
                ...state,
                copy: [...prepCopy]
            };
```

So either I use both those Actions at once, or nada. Literally: When I use both, I get two JS Objects added per cycle. When I use only one, I get 0 JS objects added per cycle. Wut.

Like, should I report a bug to React's team?

2nd edit: here is a fully working code sandbox. Check the console.log statements when you click a button https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-heisenberg-iczww

Comment: try `copy: [...newCopy]`

Comment: I tried it. It sort of works but now I have a new problem: I have to use it in both Reducer Actions and get *two* objects added, or else I get an empty array still. I'll edit my OP with an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the `action` you're passing in?

Comment: I noticed in your full code snipped you're using variabled that are outside the `reducer`s scope. Any reason why?
Additionally, check out the Redux dev tools and see what parameters the actions are being fired with.

Comment: The action.payload looks like this: [component, id] where ```"component"``` is one of "Header", "Headline", "Text Area", "Image", "Email Field" or "Footer" and ```"id"``` is one of ```0, 1, 2, ...```

re: variables outside of the ```reducer```s scope: You know what, I'll remove them. I don't even remember why I had it like that. I think it had something to do with my IDE telling me I had already declared a variable elsewhere in the program (since I do repeat ```stateArray = [...state.components]``` over and over)

Comment: Is that true for both actions? If so, shouldn't PREP_COPY also be `prepCopy.push({ webCopy: "", id: action.payload[1] });`?

Comment: I have ```prepCopy: id => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.PREP_COPY, payload: id })``` in my Dispatch. So there's only one value for ```action.payload``` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `Pallette.js` in your codesandbox link. On line 29, you call `this.props.copy.pop()`, which removes the last element from `copy`. `props.copy` is the same array as `state.copy`, so you're mutating state every time `addComponent` is called. If you change this:

```
nextCopyId = this.props.copy.pop().id + 1;
```

to this:

```
nextCopyId = this.props.copy[this.props.copy.length - 1].id + 1;
```

or this:

```
nextCopyId = [...this.props.copy].pop().id + 1;
```

`state.copy` is no longer an empty array.

In general when working with React and Redux, make sure to avoid mutative methods as much as possible. Prefer `concat` over `push` or `unshift`. Prefer `map`, `filter`, or `reduce` (which all return a copy of the array) over `forEach` or a `for` loop (which encourages you to mutate the array). Sometimes mutation is unavoidable, but be cautious and aware that when you mutate arrays/objects coming from props, you're affecting the state as well!

Comment: THANK YOU! and thank you for going exploring into my code. 

I didn't know .pop() would mutate the state, I thought it would just stay the same value despite .popping. TIL!

I will take notes on your answer re: ```concat, map, filter && reduce```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried returning copy as a new array? It's solved problems for me before

You can just use the spread operator to create it:

```
  return {
    ...state,
    components: stateArray,
    uniqueIdCounter: idIteration,
    copy: [...newCopy]
  };
```

Another, similar method would eliminate the need to push the value onto a temporary variable:

```
  return {
    ...state,
    components: stateArray,
    uniqueIdCounter: idIteration,
    copy: [...state.copy, { webCopy: "", id: action.payload[1] }]
  };
```

Comment: So get this. I tried your solution. It either successfully updates the array when I use it in ```.PREP_COPY``` **and** ```.ADD_COMPONENT```, or not at all. Meaning, I have to use it in BOTH of them to get it to work -- just one . And then the app of course adds *two* objects. Trying the ```spread``` operator in just one of the Actions yields the same empty array. WTF. Sigh

Comment: Why do you need both actions?

Comment: In theory I don't. But commenting out either one of ```.PREP_COPY``` or the ```copy``` related parts of ```.ADD_COMPONENT``` returns me to the original state of having ```state.copy``` equal to an empty array after using the Actions. I literally have to call both at once to get it to add anything. I don't understand how that could be, but it is.